# ERROR : single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I want update department_name to deparment_name and '_1' (example: Administration_1 ) to  list which devide by 2 but here is error,please help to write correctly answer. 
ERROR : single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
UPDATE departments
SET department_name= (SELECT department_name || '_1' from departments)
WHERE  manager_id=
(select manager_id from  employees 
WHERE  MOD( manager_id, 2) != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using merge

```
MERGE INTO departments a
    USING ( SELECT department_name || '_1' as name,
            DEPARTMENT_ID from departments
            WHERE  manager_id in (
           (select manager_id from  employees 
            WHERE  MOD( manager_id, 2) != 0)
           )
         ) b
    ON ( a.DEPARTMENT_ID = b.DEPARTMENT_ID )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET  a.department_name = b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update a single row with a plethora of rows (your (SELECT department_name || '_1' from departments))
I think you can simply do

```
SET department_name= department_name || '_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
UPDATE departments
SET department_name= SELECT department_name || '_1' 
WHERE  exists
     (select employees.manager_id from  employees where departments.manager_id =employees.manager_id
      and MOD( employees.manager_id, 2) != 0)
```